# JTable to Excel

Tags: java, excel, jtable

Apache POI подключен, файл и лист создать получается, но как вывести мою JTable в Excel?

```
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("mySheet");




        for (int i = 0; i < table.getModel().getRowCount(); i++) {
            row = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < table.getModel().getColumnCount(); j++) {
                String type = table.getModel().getColumnClass(j).getName();
                cell = row.createCell(j);

    }
        }
        // fos;
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("mY.xls")) {

            wb.write(fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Таблица:**

```
static String[] columnNames = {"Столбец",
             "Столбец",
             "Столбец",
             "Столбец",
             "Столбец",
             "Столбец"
   };

   static String[][] data = {
             {"информация", "информация", "информация", "информация", "информация", "информация"},
            {"информация", "информация", "информация", "информация", "информация", "информация"},
{"информация", "информация", "информация", "информация", "информация", "информация"},
   };

JTable table = new JTable(Tables.data, Tables.columnNames);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.setCellValue((String) table.getModel().getValueAt(i, j));
```

В гайде же все написано: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html